# Default enumerate item style

Tags: beamer, enumerate

Overleaf has changed recently its enumerate item default style for a colorized circle with a white number inside.

I strongly prefer the former style with a color number (without a circle).

I've learned to change this style by using "\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]" in each enumerate list.

Is there a way to change it for the whole document in the preamble?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question. Enumerate normally do not use colorized items. You probably need to specify that you are using `beamer` etc. And please provide a complete but minimal example that others can copy and test on their own

Comment: In particular, please do tell us which `beamer` theme(s) you employ.